# How can I typehint Tensorflow API types, for example tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize return value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, type-hinting, pylint

How can I typehint my_var in the following code?

```
my_var: <???> = tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize(...)
```

I've tried to find the result type in the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/optimizer/differential_evolution_minimize) with no success.

Comment: it returns a `namedtuple` called `DifferentialEvolutionOptimizerResults` in  [tensorflow_probability/python/optimizer/differential_evolution.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/e3d67c00ab491f4314a3d3e8c2cde19c8aa7490e/tensorflow_probability/python/optimizer/differential_evolution.py#L56)
... import that and type it as such. the tensorflow ecosystem had pretty poor typing support last time I checked. I expect you'll need to look at the source to find the types

Comment: many thx, that is an answer. I used to ctrl click in my code to go to the source  this time (and general for tf an keras it is not working, my limited Python ecosystem knowledge is not enough to know the appropriate method, or requirements) Anyway, I will use github or clone the repo and text search in the future. What is really a shame the the official doc is not specifying the type of an API call return value, instead a clear text paragraph tells story about what attributes should be there...